# SQL Server 2008 XML Path - separated list using newline instead of semicolon

Tags: sql, reporting-services, substring

I have a SSRS report that uses the following query which lists comma separated names:

```
Select distinct 
    ST2.Country, st2.Location, st2.[Group], 
    substring(
    (
            Select ';'+ST1.[Sponsor]  AS [text()]
            From tbl_de_list ST1
            Where ST1.[W ID] = ST2.[W ID]            
            For XML PATH ('')
     ), 2, 1000) [sponsor]
From 
    tbl_de_list ST2
order by 
    st2.[W ID]
```

I need this to be on a new line when exported from ssrs report.

This is what I have :

```
first name, last name ; first name, last name
```

What I need (in a single column):

```
first name, last name
first name, last name
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research on Google, I tweaked my query to add a space instead of a semicolon as the separator.

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
Select distinct ST2.Country, st2.Location,st2.[Group], 
substring(
    (
        Select ';'+ST1.[Sponsor]  AS [text()]
        From tbl_de_list ST1
        Where ST1.[W ID] = ST2.[W ID]            
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000),';',@NewLineChar) [Sponsor]
From tbl_de_list ST2
order by st2.[W ID]
```

When you export the report to excel/csv, it's pushed to a new line.

Comment: Glad you found your answer!  Don't forget to [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) - that will help future searchers to spot that this question has a solution.  There's a 48-hour wait period on this, so check back in a couple of days and click the check-mark next to this answer.